# Moving files into new created directory via `gets.chomp`

Tags: ruby, mkdir

The purpose of the program is to copy images from an SD card into a new folder from a question via `gets.chomp`. I cannot find a way to create a new directory from the `gets.chomp` variable named `new_batch`. Can you advise what I am doing wrong?

```
Dir.chdir '/home/moot/pickaxe/pics'

pic_names = Dir['/media/moot/**/*.{CR2,cr2,JPG,jpg}']
puts nil
puts "What would you like to call this batch? e.g Subject_Location"
puts nil
batch_name = gets.chomp

require 'fileutils'
FileUtils::mkdir_p "#{batch_name}" 
Dir.chdir '/home/moot/pickaxe/pics/#{batch_name}'

puts nil
print "Downloading #{pic_names.length} Files: "

pic_number = 1

pic_names.each do |name|
  print 'ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ  ' 

  new_name = if pic_number < 10
    "#{batch_name} 0#{pic_number}_#{Time.now} .CR2"
  else
    "#{batch_name} #{pic_number}_#{Time.now} .CR2"
  end

  require 'fileutils'
  include FileUtils
  cp(name, new_name)  

  pic_number = pic_number + 1
end
puts nil
puts "Move Complete."
```

Comment: can you put your code in codetags ? isn't readable like that.
In your mkdir you 'd better put the path where to create the folder also, the chdir isn't necessary then

Comment: Have you tried to create it by `FileUtils::mkdir_p "/home/moot/pickaxe/pics/#{batch_name}"` ?

Comment: Thanks Yevgeniy, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

why don't simply something like this?

```
Dir.mkdir("#{batch_name}")
```